# Finding the path of a specific WordPress install

Tags: wp-filesystem

I have recently taken over a WordPress website.

Once I got access to the server I found that there were more than 70 installations of WordPress spread across it (files and DBs).

What is the quickest/easiest way for me to determine which installation is the one that is running the actual live website?

I thought of putting a PHP file into each installation (a file that echoed something along the lines of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`) - then try and access that file from the site itself, from there I know which installation is the correct one (I can then work out which DB is the correct one from the wp-config).

But surely there is an easier way?  I have access to wp-admin, is there anything I can do in there to show me the base install path of this particular WordPress?

Comment: Are the files that are spread across the server in folders? You might try checking the domain itself to see which folder it points to.  Depending on the host company, that info should be in the Control Panel/Plesk interface - for example, with IONOS you'd go to Domains, then click on the domain to see it's details including it's destination (folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already figured this out, as you have admin access to the dashboard, just go into Appearance->Theme Editor then add some PHP into the theme's footer.php or functions.php to echo out the location of the install on the server.